# bash script in cronjob cannot execute /sbin/fake-hwclock

Tags: bash, permissions, cron

I've edited my **root** `crontab` to periodically execute a script:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Which should execute the following script, located on a mounted USB, as **root**:

```
* * * * * /mnt/usb0/fake-hwclock-cron.sh
```

The script (1) `fake-hwclock-cron.sh` then runs the script (2) `fake-hwclock` to save the current time:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$(fake-hwclock save)"
```

The script (2) `fake-hwclock` (located in *"/sbin/fake-hwclock"*) then saves the time to the file (3) `fake-hwclock.data` on a mounted USB.

The USB is automatically mounted with the following options:

```
PARTUUID=1c921a37-01 /mnt/usb0 ext4 defaults,auto,users,rw,nofail 0 0
```

---

File Permissions:

```
(1) -rwxrwxrwx 1 pi   pi    /mnt/usb0/fake-hwclock-cron.sh
(2) -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  /sbin/fake-hwclock
(3) -rwxrwxrwx 1 pi   pi    /mnt/usb0/fake-hwclock.data
```

If I understood it correct, for the files (1) `fake-hwclock-cron.sh` and (3) `fake-hwclock.data` every user can read/write/execute.
For file (2) `fake-hwclock` every user can read/execute.

.. but ignoring these permissions for a second, isn't the *cron job*, which is executed as sudo, executing the script (1) `fake-hwclock-cron.sh` with **su** rights as well?

And what's even more confusing: I can execute both scripts (1) / (2) without **su** rights in the shell, but I cant execute them with **su** rights as a cron job.

---

So, can anyone explain to me why I get a *"Permission denied"* error?

`/bin/sh: 1: /mnt/usb0/fake-hwclock-cron.sh: Permission denied`

---

**P.S.** I hope i've managed to explain well enough; otherwise please tell me

Comment: Is the `/mnt/usb0` filesystem mounted with the `noexec` option?

Comment: No, it isnt. Thanks for pointing that out, I've updated the post.

Comment: Can you show us the full contents of `/mnt/usb0/fake-hwclock-cron.sh`? Oh, and what operating system is this?

Comment: That is the full content, it should only execute this ONE command.

Comment: So there is no [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))?

Comment: what about if you execute the script in cron like `* * * * * sh /mnt/usb0/fake-hwclock-cron.sh`? i. e adding `sh` in front of the script to execute. and what does `mount |grep usb0` says? is that the same thing as you believe it's mounted with?

Comment: @terdon well okay, yes there is a shebang line. I've updated the post.

Comment: @αғsнιη Hmm actually it returns `fake-hwclock: not found`. Probably it doesn't find the command. What's the difference to `/bin/sh`? Because that returned the same error. And even weirder: `mount | grep usb0` returns `type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)`

Comment: no, now it's different error, which confirm your mount point is mounted with noexec (and you see the `mount` output for that now) option. for the later error, _`comnnad not found`_ you need to provide the full path of the command and it will work then

Comment: @αғsнιη Wow, that actually would've never come in to my mind. Would you mind adding it as answer? I am curious in "why the USB isn't mounted as defined" and "why the command cannot be found without defining the full path"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the output of the `mount |grep usb0` it shows that the mount point is mounted by the `noexec` option and it will prevent you just executing the script but you can do execute it with shell interpreter directly like:

```
* * * * * sh /path/to/script.sh
```

for the later error *`fake-hwclock: not found`*, you would need to provide the full of the `fake-hwclock` commnad.

see more about [noexec](/a/490411/72456).

Comment: Sadly I cannot upvote yet, thanks (to everybody) for the help though!